# Having trouble using an array that is returned by a function in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function that generates values in an array and returns a pointer to that array. Here's the MWE code:

```
int *f(size_t s)
{
    int *ret=new int[s];
    for(size_t a=0;a<s;a++)
    {
    ret[a]=a;
    cout << ret[a] << endl;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

note that I have a `cout` line in for for loop to prove to myself that the array is being populated properly.

Now, here's my problem. I can't find the correct method of using the returned array. Here's what I've been doing:

```
int main (void)
{
 int ary_siz = 10;
 int ary[ary_siz];
 *ary = *f(ary_siz);
 cout << ary[0] << endl;
 cout << ary[2] << endl;
 cout << ary[3] << endl;
}
```

The first element in `ary` seems to be right. The others (`ary[1]`,`ary[2]`...) are not. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: After addressing the points made in the answers, you might be surprised to find that `ary[1]` still doesn't print out.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo. ary[1] and I have never gotten along anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
int main (void)
{
 int ary_siz = 10;
 int *ary = f(ary_siz);
 cout << ary[0] << endl;
 cout << ary[2] << endl;
 cout << ary[3] << endl;
 delete [] ary;
}
```

Comment: mmmm... you stole the `delete[]` part :)

Comment: Didn't mean to -- just didn't think about it until after I posted the first answer.  +1 to you for posting that first though.

Comment: Vaughn (and sehe) - Gracias amigos. This works -- AND it points up the core of my confusion. Most of the error msgs I was getting related to type errors (e.g. 'can't convert int to *int...blah blah), and, given this Q&A: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html, I thought the problem was that I was just not getting what the returned type really was. BUT, in your answer, you are not declaring a pointer-to-int-array to initialize to the returned array, you just have a normal pointer-to-int. But then you are treating it like an array, which I thought the Q&A I posted said was verboten.

Comment: I'm frustrated because I'm reduced to code-copying without understanding what's happening. I've read many, seemingly contradictory things about pointers and arrays. Blerk.

Comment: @bev: that's good. I'm very happy your not simply accepting it. This means you'll be one of those who will _actually_ understand in the end. However, it is also largely off topic! Did you know there is a chat room for c++ on StackOverflow here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec?

Comment: @sehe Ah. Sorry bout being off the reservation. I'll mend my ways. And thanks for the pointer-to-chat. I'll check it out.

Comment: @bev: Pointers and arrays are not the same thing, but they can be used in similar ways.  The difference is subtle.  You'll probably need to see a lot of examples before it really makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment

```
*ary = *f(ary_siz);
```

copies a single element. Use

```
int main (void)
{
 int ary_siz = 10;
 int *ary = f(ary_siz);

 delete[] ary;
}
```

fixing the memory leak as well

Comment: Thanks sehe. I have my own memory leak when it comes to memory leaks :-).

Answer (score 1):

You allocate an array in the function and you just assign its first element to the first element of your stack-allocated array, instead of just using the returned array.

you should do something like that:

```
int main (void)
{
 int ary_siz = 10;
 int *ary;
 ary = f(ary_siz);
 cout << ary[0] << endl;
 cout << ary[2] << endl;
 cout << ary[3] << endl;
 delete[] ary // don't forget to release the memory
 return 0; // You should return something in the main function
}
```

Moreover, in C++ you should use vectors instead of "bare-metal" arrays whenever possible.

Comment: Using `std::array<>` is also acceptable (in addition to `std::vector<>`). Also, `main` does not require a return value; `0` is returned by default in the absence of an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: Never heard of std::array: is it a new feature of C++11? As for the missing `return` statement, I consider it bad style, more of an indication of a forgot explicit return.

Comment: `std::array<>` is the C++11 implementation of TR1's `std::tr1::array<>`, which in turn is TR1's implementation of Boost's `boost::array<>`. As for missing `return`, I'd say it's highly unusual for an application's return code to have any relevance or meaning, so it should only be present if it's a non-default return value. But, this is of course entirely subjective.

Comment: @akappa - thanks. And thanks for the reminder about releasing the memory and returning something in main. I hadn't known that.

Comment: Also, I'm implementing your suggestion about vectors. Here's a question: Is a vector a class wrapper around a 'bare-metal' array? In other words, are all the things that are true for arrays true for vectors?

Comment: @bev: implementations usually (necessarily?) wraps a **dynamically** allocated array, which is reallocated when needed when pushing or popping elements. I don't know what the standard says about the complexity of its operations, but I think it's assured that all its operations (adding, accessing, removing elements) are guaranteed to have a complexity which is the same of the complexity of these operation on an array.

Comment: @akappa Hmmm. Thanks for the reply. It requires a little pondering from me, tho, before I see whether your answer removes my ignorance on this subject

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
int *ary = f(ary_siz);
```

The you can just use the [] operator as you do in the couts.